# TortoiseORM - Table Relationships with Inheritance

Tags: tortoise-orm

I would like to create a slightly more complex data model in TortoiseORM which is proving to be quite difficult. The idea of the datamodel is as follows:

Media: Regular table.

```
class Media(models.Model):
    id: str = fields.CharField(max_length=20, pk=True)
    type = fields.CharEnumField(MediaType)
    url: str = fields.CharField(max_length=512)
    thumbnail_url: str = fields.CharField(max_length=512)
    medium_thumbnail_url: str = fields.CharField(max_length=512)
    order: int = fields.IntField()
    product = fields.ForeignKeyField('models.Product', related_name='media', on_delete=fields.CASCADE)
```

Product: Not a table. Just a mixin.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    id = fields.CharField(max_length=12, pk=True, index=True)
    date_created = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_last_updated = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now=True)
    [...]
    description = fields.TextField(null=True)
    thumbnail_url = fields.CharField(max_length=512)
    medium_thumbnail_url = fields.CharField(max_length=512)
    media = fields.ReverseRelation[Media]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Vehicle: Not a table. Just a mixin. Inherits from Product.

```
class Vehicle(Product):
    year = fields.IntField()
    make = fields.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = fields.CharField(max_length=100)
    vin = fields.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    odometer = fields.IntField()
    color = fields.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Motorcycle: Regular table. Inherits from Vehicle. No new variables.

```
class Motorcycle(Vehicle):
    pass
```

Parts: Regular table. Inherits from Product. No new variables.

```
class Parts(Product):
    pass
```

The issue I am running into is the one to many relationship between the different product types and the media objects.

Whenever I try to create the media objects:

```
if product_create.media:
    i, media_objs = 0, []
    for media_obj in product_create.media:
        media_obj: MediaCreate = media_obj
        media_objs.append(Media(product=product,
                                id=get_random_alphanumeric_string(20),
                                type=media_obj.type,
                                url=media_obj.url,
                                thumbnail_url=media_obj.thumbnail_url,
                                medium_thumbnail_url=media_obj.medium_thumbnail_url,
                                order=i))
        i += 1

    await Media.bulk_create(media_objs)
```

I run into an error with:

```
line 119, in get_related_model
    return cls.apps[related_app_name][related_model_name]
KeyError: 'Product'

[...]
tortoise.exceptions.ConfigurationError: No model with name 'Product' registered in app 'models'.
```

It seems that the challenge here is to create a foreign key relationship in Tortoise ORM that can dynamically reference different models in an inheritance hierarchy.

I tried looking through the Tortoise documentation, but I couldn't find anything on this specifically. Any help would be greatly appreciated.